# Can you assign a 50% probability to an unknown situation?

Tags: probability

Say I have a bag of 5 balls. I know there is some mixture of red and black balls in the bag. I pull out 4 balls and replace as follows: Red, Black, Red, Black.

Can I assume there is a 50% chance the next ball I pull out is Red if I have no other information about the ball.

What if I had not yet pulled any balls out of the bag?

Comment: You can assign prior probabilities as you see fit to a given situation, but if you want to adopt a general principle like "probabilities I am ignorant of should be assigned the value 1/2" you can rapidly arrive at inconsistencies.

Comment: It depends on what it costs you to be wrong.  After all, it is mathematically provable that the chance cannot be 50%!